# How To Get Friends Profile Pic in fb

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api

```
FB_Graph_Response = [FB_Graph doGraphGet:@"me/friends" withGetVars:nil];

//  NSLog(@"%@",[FB_Graph_Response.htmlResponse JSONValue]);


arrFriendsList = [[[FB_Graph_Response.htmlResponse JSONValue]objectForKey:@"data"]retain];
```

I have accessed the friends list in my app by using fb graph api(above request),
    but i am not able to get friend's profile images. how to get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the id (or the nick) of the user, and get the picture from https://graph.facebook.com/idOrNick/picture
This works without any kind of auth.
Small sample:

```
NSString id = getTheIdOrNick;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture", id]];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
//UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
//imgView.image = image;
```